# Why is fetch_assoc() not returning a value?

Tags: php, mysqli

For the life of me I can't figure out why fetch_assoc() is returning false here:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
print("Username is " . $username . "<br>");

//Create query
$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "'");
print($query . "<br>");

//Run query
if (!$result = $db2 -> query($query)) {
    print("Query failed!");
}

if (!$user = new LG_User($result))
    print("Failed to create user!<br>");

while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows);
print("User is " . $user -> first_name . "<br>");
```

The query is successful and the new user object is created, because the last line of code is printing $user->first_name correctly. I'm using the very same block of code to populate the $rows array on another page and it is working. What am I doing wrong here? If I try to use

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}`

instead of

`while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}`

it still doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: new LG_User($result) ? var_dump($result) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown the code for the `LG_User` constructor, but if it's filling in `$user` from the database, it must be calling a `fetch` function itself. So when it returns, all the rows of the result have been fetched, and there's nothing left for your loop to read.

You can go back to the beginning of the result set with the [`data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) method.

```
if (!$user = new LG_User($result))
    print("Failed to create user!<br>");
$result->data_seek(0);
while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: That's it! You're my hero -- I'm embarrassed to say how long I've been sitting at this console trying to debug this issues. Thank you!